# Finding the direction / winding direction of a CGPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

When rendering overlapping CGPath's, Apple uses a winding-rule to decide whether to render both of them solid, or use one of them to cut-out a piece of the other one.

I want all my CGPath's to be solid, but I can't tell users "draw them this way around OR ELSE", so I need to detect when the winding-direction is opposite to normal, and then reverse it.

I know how to reverse all the elements of a path using CGPathApply (although it's a lot of boilerplate code) - but how do you access the winding direction of a CGPath? Hasn't Apple already calculated this (since they use it internally)?

Worst case, I'll also re-implement the wheel, and make another CGPathApply that calculates winding - but that seems excessively boilerplate / error prone, so if there's an Apple source for this info...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [even-odd fill rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106) instead? Then the direction of each subpath doesn't affect the result. The users would at least see a consistent weird result and would be able to figure out not to do that.

Anyway, there isn't really a fundamental "winding direction" of a path. The fill rule always evaluates the winding *at a point*.

Imagine a figure-eight path, where one lobe goes in a clockwise direction and the other goes counterclockwise. The winding at a point inside one lobe is different than the winding in the other lobe.

I think if you want to force your object to be "solid" you'll have to do some surgery on the paths that the user inputs. Again, it may be easier to give a consistent result and let the user figure out how to do that themselves.

Comment: EO is the opposite of what I'm asking for in the question, so I don't see how that would help. c.f. "I want all my CGPath's to be solid".

Comment: re: figure-of-eight - ouch. As it happens, that's very unlikelky to get drawn, because of the nature of the app, but I get your point. I can add something to the drawing phase to prevent self-intersection, although it's likely to only happen as an accident on the user's side.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wrote my own. Pseudocode:

1. use CGPathApplier to run a custom function
2. convert each node to a custom object (since Apple's API is non-OOP)
3. iterate over all nodes, and if you find a CLOSE which is not the final node, split (you have multiple sub-paths), and re start the algorithm with each subpath
4. iterate over all nodes, pick a point halfway along each line-segment, and then step 1 pixel to the left, one pixel to the right (where "left/right" means "perpendicular to direction of line"
5. ask Apple "is (pixel to left) inside path?"
6. ditto pixel to right
7. if all are to left = winding a
8. if all are to right = winding b
9. if mix of left/right = alert the user that their shape crosses itself, and everything's going to go weird and wrong